# RaiseError not appearing from Trigger in Calling Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, errorlevel, raiserror

We have an old product that has moved forward slowly over the years from originally being built in SQL Server 2000 and the problem ralates to how SQL bubbles up the Errors from RaiseError calls.

For instance I have a trigger on a table that raises an error similar to this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Rotation_UTrig]
ON [dbo].[Rotation] FOR UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
.
.
.
    /* * VALIDATION RULE FOR FIELD 'RotationYear' */
            RAISERROR ('Invalid value entered for RotationYear, must be >=0', 44444, 1)
            goto fatalerror
.
.
fatalerror:
END
```

This has the required effect in the calling procedure that the if statement has a value for `@@Error`:

```
 update Rotation 
 set OrderedQuantity = @OrderedQuantity, 
     DespatchedQuantity = @DespatchedQuantity 
 where ID = @RotationNo

 if @@Error != 0
 begin
    if @AlreadyInTrans = 0 begin rollback transaction end
        raiserror ('Error on update of Rotation.', 16, 1)
        goto fatalerror
end
.
.
.
fatalerror:
```

but the error seen by the parent calling application is:

> Error Severity levels greater than 18 can only be specified by members of the sysadmin role, using WITH LOG option

This is because the error level is 44444 in the trigger, if I add

```
With LOG
```

to the trigger code for `Raiserror` then this closes the connection (which we do NOT want). If I lower the error level to 16 in the trigger then the

```
if @@Error !=0
```

line does not hit as `@@Error` is set to zero.

Other than using a

```
Try... Catch
```

around the update statement in the parent procedure, is there any other way to bubble up the `@@Error` value into the procedure which does the update so that the procedure code (the update statement and the following if @@Error != 0) can remain unchanged? If not then this is a massive change to my application as I'll need to change all the locations where the impacted tables are being updated as well as to all the triggers.

Comment: I know this is legacy code but once you start seeing the GOTO statement it is time to roll up your sleeves and pull your code out of the dark ages and start using TRY/Catch. It has been available as a much better error handling technique for over a decade now.

Comment: The other huge code smell in the little bit of code you posted is that you have scalar variables throughout. This is a pretty good indication that your triggers are assuming there will only ever be a single row operation. They need to be rewritten as a set based approach to handle multiple rows.

Comment: what if you raise another error after `fatalerror:`?

Comment: this is old code, but otherwise functioning well and a rewrite at this stage will risk adding a lot more bugs, so a rewrite is further down the line. For now i need to find out how to get the Raiseerror error to buble up into @@error or use a different variable but im not sure what that would be.

Comment: I've tried adding another error after fatalerror in the trigger, no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! The issue is that when another trigger comes along and works through with no problems, @@Error is being reset to 0.